# Annotate data points while plotting from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I would like to annotate the data points with their values next to the points on the plot. The examples I found only deal with x and y as vectors. However, I would like to do this for a pandas DataFrame that contains multiple columns.

```
ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
df.plot(ax = ax)
plt.show()
```

What is the best way to annotate all the points for a multi-column DataFrame?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Do you want to use one of the other columns as the text of the annotation? This is something I did recently.

Starting with some example data

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
           x         y val
 0 -1.015235  0.840049   a
 1 -0.427016  0.880745   b
 2  0.744470 -0.401485   c
 3  1.334952 -0.708141   d
 4  0.127634 -1.335107   e
```

Plot the points. I plot y against x, in this example.

```
ax = df.set_index('x')['y'].plot(style='o')
```

Write a function that loops over x, y, and the value to annotate beside the point.

```
def label_point(x, y, val, ax):
    a = pd.concat({'x': x, 'y': y, 'val': val}, axis=1)
    for i, point in a.iterrows():
        ax.text(point['x'], point['y'], str(point['val']))

label_point(df.x, df.y, df.val, ax)

draw()
```

[image: Annotated Points]

Answer (score 63):

Here's a (very) slightly slicker version of [Dan Allan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15911372/2071807):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.rand(10), 'y':np.random.rand(10)}, 
                  index=list(string.ascii_lowercase[:10]))
```

Which gives:

```
          x         y
a  0.541974  0.042185
b  0.036188  0.775425
c  0.950099  0.888305
d  0.739367  0.638368
e  0.739910  0.596037
f  0.974529  0.111819
g  0.640637  0.161805
h  0.554600  0.172221
i  0.718941  0.192932
j  0.447242  0.172469
```

And then:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot('x', 'y', kind='scatter', ax=ax)

for k, v in df.iterrows():
    ax.annotate(k, v)
```

Finally, if you're in interactive mode you might need to refresh the plot:

```
fig.canvas.draw()
```

Which produces:
[image: Boring scatter plot]

Or, since that looks incredibly ugly, you can beautify things a bit pretty easily:

```
from matplotlib import cm
cmap = cm.get_cmap('Spectral')
df.plot('x', 'y', kind='scatter', ax=ax, s=120, linewidth=0, 
        c=range(len(df)), colormap=cmap)

for k, v in df.iterrows():
    ax.annotate(k, v,
                xytext=(10,-5), textcoords='offset points',
                family='sans-serif', fontsize=18, color='darkslategrey')
```

Which looks a lot nicer:
[image: Nice scatter plot]

Comment: Beautiful! (The second plot as you said...)

Comment: @LondonRob, is there anyway you can tell me how we can annotate only every other nth marker?

Comment: @st19297 Create a new question! And include a link to this answer (see the "share" link) so people know where you're starting from!

Comment: The problem I have had with this method is that the labels get truncated if they go outside the plot area. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @HowardLovatt, you can reset the axis limits with `xlim=[0,1]` and `ax.set(xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)` and if you need to calculate the limits dynamically, you can start with `df[x].max()` and adjust by multiplying by `0.9` or `1.1`, say.

Comment: @PatrickT Many thanks.

Answer (score 35):

Let's assume your `df` has multiple columns, and three of which are `x`, `y`, and `lbl`. To annotate your `(x,y)` scatter plot with `lbl`, simply:

```
ax = df.plot(kind='scatter',x='x',y='y')
df[['x','y','lbl']].apply(lambda row: ax.text(*row),axis=1);
```

Comment: For the first line, current pandas would use df.plot('x', 'y', kind='scatter')

Answer (score 12):

I found the previous answers quite helpful, especially [LondonRob's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26000515/2071807) that improved the layout a bit.

The only thing that bothered me is that I don't like pulling data out of DataFrames to then loop over them. Seems a waste of the DataFrame.

Here was an alternative that avoids the loop using .apply(), and includes the nicer-looking annotations (I thought the color scale was a bit overkill and couldn't get the colorbar to go away):

```py
ax = df.plot('x', 'y', kind='scatter', s=50 )

def annotate_df(row):  
    ax.annotate(row.name, row.values,
                xytext=(10,-5), 
                textcoords='offset points',
                size=18, 
                color='darkslategrey')
    
_ = df.apply(annotate_df, axis=1)
```

[image]

#### *Edit Notes*

*I edited my code example recently. Originally it used the same:*

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

*as the other posts to expose the axes, however this is unnecessary and makes the:*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

*line also unnecessary.*

*Also note:*

- *If you are trying to reproduce this example and your plots don't have the points in the same place as any of ours, it may be because the DataFrame was using random values. It probably would have been less confusing if we'd used a fixed data table or a random seed.*
- *Depending on the points, you may have to play with the `xytext` values to get better placements.*