# Pandas simple X Y plot

Tags: python-2.7, plot, pandas

Looks simple but I am not able to draw a X-Y chart with "dots" in pandas DataFrame.
I want to show the **subid** as "Mark" on X Y Chart with X as **age** and Y as **fdg** .

Code so far

```
mydata = [{'subid': 'B14-111', 'age': 75, 'fdg': 3}, {'subid': 'B14-112', 'age': 22, 'fdg': 2}, {'subid': 'B14-112', 'age': 40, 'fdg': 5}]

df = pandas.DataFrame(mydata)

DataFrame.plot(df,x="age",y="fdg")

show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 27):

`df.plot()` will accept matplotlib `kwargs`.  See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot)

```
mydata = [{'subid': 'B14-111', 'age': 75, 'fdg': 3}, {'subid': 'B14-112', 'age': 22, 
           'fdg': 2}, {'subid': 'B14-112', 'age': 40, 'fdg': 5}]

df = pandas.DataFrame(mydata)
df = df.sort(['age'])  # dict doesn't preserve order
df.plot(x='age', y='fdg', marker='.')
```

[image]

Reading your question again, I'm thinking you might actually be asking for a scatterplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(df['age'], df['fdg'])
```

Have a look at the [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#module-matplotlib.pyplot) docs.

Comment: Thanks for both the answer. However how to put name of "subid" with the dots.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910019/annotate-data-points-while-plotting-from-pandas-dataframe/15911372#15911372

Comment: `matplotlib.pyplot`.  He probably started ipython with the `--pylab` flag which imports that (and a bunch of other stuff) automatically.

Comment: Correct. Once you use ``ipython --pylab``, you'll never go back. It's bad practice to import pylab globally into a module, but when I'm working interactively I think it's dead useful.

Comment: n.b. `df.sort()` is now deprecated for [`df.sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Answer (score 4):

Try following for a scatter diagram.

```
import pandas
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

mydata = [{'subid': 'B14-111', 'age': 75, 'fdg': 3}, {'subid': 'B14-112', 'age': 22, 
           'fdg': 2}, {'subid': 'B14-112', 'age': 40, 'fdg': 5}]

df = pandas.DataFrame(mydata)
x,y = [],[]

x.append (df.age)
y.append (df.fdg)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(y,x,'o-')
plt.show()
```