# pandas scatterplot with labels/colours from a qualitative column

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

This is a very basic question but there must be something I'm missing. My data looks like this:

```
    x   y   z
0   2.7 0.3 a
1   3.4 0.4 b
2   15  1.9 b
3   3   0.4 c
4   7.4 0.8 a
```

Where `z` has `n` qualitative values. I would like to plot `(x,y)` using `z` as a label (i.e. `n` different colours, etc.). The way I do it now is essentially restricting to the individual values of `z`, looping over them and do one scatterplot at a time. Is there a quicker option?

**EDIT**: this is my current solution

```
for i, z in zip(range(4), ["a", "b", "c", "d"]):
    df.xs(z).plot(kind="scatter", label=z, x="x", y="y", color=colours[i], ax=ax)
```

where `colours` and `ax` are defined elsewhere. The reasons why I dislike this solution are

1. Why do I have to put colours manually, I already have a palette and normal plots already loop through it.
2. Why should I care about `ax`, Pandas should take care of everything.
3. (*most important!*) I don't want to loop through either `["a", "b", "c", "d"]` or `set(df.z)`.

Comment: I think this answers your question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910019/annotate-data-points-while-plotting-from-pandas-dataframe/15911372#15911372

Comment: I edited my question to explain where I am already. I am just surprised that Pandas doesn't provide such basic functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[2.7, 3.4, 15, 3, 7.4], columns=['x'])
df['y'] = [ 0.3, 0.4, 1.9, 0.4, 0.8]
df['z'] = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a']


ax = df.set_index('x')['y'].plot(style='o')

def label_point(x, y, val, ax):
    a = pd.concat({'x': x, 'y': y, 'val': val}, axis=1)
    for i, point in a.iterrows():
        ax.text(point['x'], point['y'], str(point['val']))

label_point(df.x, df.y, df.z, ax)

draw()
```