# Adding annotations to a Matplotlib scatter graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

I have plotted the 2nd and 3rd column from my Excel datasheet on a scatter graph using:

```
df.plot.scatter(x="volume", y="Cost per m^3") 
plt.title("Volume vs. Cost Analysis", size = 16)
plt.ylim((0,80000))
plt.xlim((0.4e+7,1.6e+7))
```

How can I annotate these points with their 1st column correspondents?

Comment: You can use annotations: https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Annotate data points while plotting from Pandas DataFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910019/annotate-data-points-while-plotting-from-pandas-dataframe)