# labeling data points with dataframe including empty cells

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, annotate

I have an Excel sheet like this:

```
A    B    C    D
3    1    2    8
4    2    2    8
5    3    2    9
          2    9
6    4    2    7
```

Now I am trying to plot 'B' over 'C' and label the data points with the entrys of 'A'. It should show me the points 1/2, 2/2, 3/2 and 4/2 with the corresponding labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os

df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "./Datenbank/Test.xlsx"))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot('B', 'C', kind='scatter', ax=ax)
df[['B','C','A']].apply(lambda x: ax.text(*x),axis=1);

plt.show()
```

Unfortunately I am getting this:

[image]

with the Error:

```
ValueError: posx and posy should be finite values
```

As you can see it did not label the last data point. I know it is because of the empty cells in the sheet but i cannot avoid them. There is just no measurement data at this positions. 
I already searched for a solution here:
[Annotate data points while plotting from Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910019/annotate-data-points-while-plotting-from-pandas-dataframe/15911372#15911372)
but it did not solve my problem.

So, is there a way to still label the last data point?

P.S.: The excel sheet is just an example. So keep in mind in reality there are many empty cells at different positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply trash the invalid data rows from df before plotting them

```
df = df[df['B'].notnull()]
```