# Scatter plot to add Dates as data labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, scatter-plot

Plotting scatters I am using below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()

dates = ['2015-12-20','2015-09-12','2015-08-12','2015-06-12']  
PM_25 = [68, 66, 55, 46]

dates = [pd.to_datetime(d) for d in dates]

plt.scatter(dates, PM_25, s =50, c = 'red')
plt.show()
```

For each of the scatters, I want to add data label 'date' to it. So I made these changes:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(dates, PM_25)
for i, txt in enumerate(dates):
    ax.annotate(txt, i)
```

[image]

It doesn't work.

What's the right way to label them? Thank you.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910019/annotate-data-points-while-plotting-from-pandas-dataframe/15911372#15911372

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need both `x` and `y` when you annotate.

```
for i, txt in enumerate(dates):
    ax.annotate(txt, (dates[i],PM_25[i]))
```

Comment: thanks! any advise to change the label format to "yyyy-mm-dd" instead of now "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"?

Comment: Use `Timestamp.strftime`: `ax.annotate(txt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), (dates[i],PM_25[i]))`.